# In React, why am I getting these errors around Promises?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm integrating Firebase into my React app, and using TypeScript. Firebase is imported from `firebase.js`, which is:

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
  }

  doEmailUpdate = (email:string) => {
    if (app.auth().currentUser) {
      return app.auth().currentUser?.updateEmail(email)
    }
    return Promise.reject();
  }

  ... more functions ...

}
 
export default Firebase;
```

First question: the Firebase function `updateEmail` returns `Promise<void>`, and the return type of `doEmailUpdate` (obtained by pressing CTRL in VSCode) is `Promise<void>|undefined`.  Why is `undefined` an option?  Surely `Promise.reject()` returns a Promise too?  Have I structured this correctly?

Secondly: what's the best way to call this function from my component and then handle the error?  I've been using:

```
firebase.doEmailUpdate(formState.email)
.then(() => {...})
.catch(error => {...})
```

but I get a TypeScript error

> Object is possibly 'undefined'

presumably because the function can return undefined.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I ensure that `updateEmail` always returns a Promise, or something which can fit into the then/catch structure?

Answer (score 3):

The culprit here is the the optional chaining operator `(?.)`. If `currentUser` were `null` or `undefined`, then your code would return `undefined` (that's what the operator does).

There's simply no need for it in this scenario and you could do:

```
let user = app.auth().currentUser;
if (user) {
   return user.updateEmail(email)
}
```

Comment: Specifically, since `app.auth()` might return something different the second time it is called.

Comment: Thank you!  I had to add in 'else Promise.reject()' as well, but it seems to be working now.

Comment: @Sharon yes, this was just supposed to be a replacement for your `if` branch. There's no need for an `else` but go with whatever code convention you use.